# change cron job for outside cron job service

Tags: php, cron, jobs

is there a way to put those cron jobs in a php file

```
* * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxxx.com; /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php-cgi artisan fc:livecron
* * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxxx.com; /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php-cgi artisan fc:taskrunner
* * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxxx.com; /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php-cgi artisan fc:ticketcron
```

so that I can use a outside cron job service which calls the php file?

Comment: Why would you want to do that when the local CRON service should work just fine?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Laravel. You can [call Artisan commands from a controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands), if that's what you want to do. But Laravel has it's own scheduler, and a local cron is so much easier.

Comment: because i got only this cron job options http://prntscr.com/eq02v9

Comment: If you have access to the command line, use `crontab -e` instead. If you don't have access, talk to your host to find out how to add tasks to your local cron.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to provide informations about your current Plesk version in use, because then we could guide you to the domain - specific scheduled tasks more easily.

The "normal" way with Plesk Onyx for example, is to go to your domain - specific subscription and just click on the "Scheduled Tasks" management option on the right side. You are able to "**run a command**", "**Fetch an URL**" and "**Run a PHP script**".

Consider to visit

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/scheduling-tasks.65207/

... for more usefull Plesk informations/documentations.

Comment: thx for your kind help, but my hoster dont gives the permission on his cloudhosting paket.i only have URL limited cronjob access